# Spacing Elements In Java

Tags: java

I am having issues with spacing my fields and buttons on my GUI when I run my java code. I am looking for some help and explanation or a direction to a well made site explaining how to easily space out elements. below is my very long code hopefully it displays well so that I do not strain your eyes.

I am trying to get spacing after the first text boxes and after the second boxes so that the buttons can be at the same x position but just shifted down in the y axis. I have tried adding new insets and pushing the buttons down but they get pushed down and to the right and nothing looks centered anymore.

```
public class theater_proceeds extends JFrame    
{

//winow dimentions

private final int wh = 300;
private final int ww = 500;

//20% gross keep
private final double percent_rev = 0.20;

//Labels
private JLabel adult_price;
private JLabel adult_num;
private JLabel child_price;
private JLabel child_num;

//Fields
private JTextField a_price;
private JTextField a_num;
private JTextField c_price;
private JTextField c_num;

//Buttons
private JButton calculate;
private JButton exit;

//panel
private JPanel theater;

private GridBagConstraints gbc;

theater_proceeds()
{
    //set the size
    setSize(ww, wh);

    //set the title
    setTitle("Theater Proceeds Calculator");

    //set exit default action
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //constraints
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //set the insets
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,60);


    //create the panel
    theater = new JPanel();

    //set the layout manager
    theater.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //initialize each pair of field and label and add them to the panel
    //starting with first 2
    adult_num = new JLabel("Number of Adults");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    theater.add(adult_num, gbc);

    a_num = new JTextField(10);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    theater.add(a_num, gbc);

    //second pair        
    adult_price = new JLabel("Price per Adult");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    theater.add(adult_price,gbc);

    a_price = new JTextField(10);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    theater.add(a_price, gbc);


    //third pair
    child_num = new JLabel("Number of Children");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    theater.add(child_num, gbc);


    c_num = new JTextField(10);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    theater.add(c_num, gbc);


    //forth pair
    child_price = new JLabel("Price per Child");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    theater.add(child_price, gbc);


    c_price = new JTextField(10);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    theater.add(c_price, gbc);


    calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 7;
    theater.add(calculate, gbc);

    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 7;
    theater.add(exit, gbc);

    add(theater);

    setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Can you screen shot an image?

Comment: (Maybe try NetBeans just to play with its GUI editor.)

Comment: I need to inquire about the GUI editor because if there is any easy way to align these things I would really adore it. The X, Y stuff does not bother me, the Insets make absolutely no sense in  my brain. I got it solved with the answer below, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the Inset for your buttons, make sure to keep your 60 right that you set for every component at the beginning.

Before adding your buttons: `gbc.insets = new Insets(50, 0, 0, 60);`

Replace 50 with whatever inset you desire.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I got it to work with your help. I am still confused on how insets effects the components of the GUI. I looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html and it specifies that insets are top, left bottm, right however it seems that once it is set than it applies to all of the elements until it is changed. For more complex things it seems like I will have to set it after every component.

Comment: @AlexTop that's the nature of the GridBagLayout manager. gbc is a GridBagConstraints object that holds your placement settings and if you don't make changes to it's state between adding components you'll keep using the same settings, including inset.

When you say `add(component, gbc);` you're saying "add component using gbc's constraints."